# pcap_inject on a disconnected interface

Tags: c, linux, libpcap, tcpreplay

I'm trying to implement replaying packets stored in .pcap files using libpcap. 
The process is very simple: I would open the pcap file with 'pcap_open_offline' then pass packets to the device opened with `pcap_open_live`, and send them with `pcap_inject` through the interface.

Now the NIC doesn't have an ethernet cable connected to it. I know that `pcap_open_live` won't tell whether the device opened supports sending, so I get errors from pcap_inject (`errno 100`). Is this to be expected? If I simply use tcpreplay from the cmd line, it finishes and presents no error, with or without the ethernet cable plugged in.

Anyone know how tcpreplay/tcpedit handles "dead" interfaces? Does tcpreplay rewrite packet headers whereas I'm trying to send them raw? Any help is appreciated!

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and the interface is address-less and in promisc mode:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    up ifconfig eth1 promisc up
    down ifconfig eth1 promisc down
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the NIC doesn't have an ethernet cable connected to it.

Then what useful result do you expect to get by sending packets on that NIC?

> I know that `pcap_open_live` won't tell whether the device opened supports sending

Whether the device is up or not can change over time, so any answer you get from `pcap_open_live()` could be incorrect by the time you actually try to send the packet.

> so I get errors from pcap_inject (`errno 100`)

Searching for 100 in Linux errno.h reveals:

```
#define ENETDOWN    100 /* Network is down */
```

I guess the Linux networking doesn't like it when people try to send packets on an interface that's down with a `send()` system call, which is what libpcap does.

> Is this to be expected?

Yes.

> If I simply use tcpreplay from the cmd line, it finishes and presents no error

tcpreplay has a whole bunch of different mechanisms it uses to send packets.  See `sendpacket()` in the `sendpacket.c` source file in the tcpreplay source.  Some of them might, for example, silently drop packets being sent on a dead interface, rather than reporting an error, and it might be using one of those mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks Guy! I verified that even though tcpreplay reports no error, the packets were indeed dropped. I was going to use the NIC as sort of a sniffer, and process only packets from the pcap files, but it was getting packets from the ethernet cable... I guess I just need to make it non-promisc

Comment: or I could use the loopback device for this purpose.... wish there was a networking book for dummies :P